# Lower the number of Append Queries in Access 2000?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have to make a report with 168 rows. Most of them are sequential data, but there are summation rows for which I need to build helper tables.

Therefore I need to build like 45-50 queries, most of them Append Queries.

Is there a way to minimize the number of queries and develop a large report with 168 rows?

Should I use code?

Comment: Although I answered this because the question is certainly useful to you, I suspect this is not a proper Stack Overflow question and subject to at least some opinionated answers.  Maybe this would be better for the Stack Exchange [Database Administrator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) forum?

Comment: Not sure. It is still connected to coding. Are database administrators coding SQL and VBA?

Comment: Just like Stack Overflow includes topic for many programming languages, Data Administrators forum is for any question germane to database admin including Access.  Your question is actually less about specific code and more about overall design and management.

Comment: Ok ok, You might be right. Wasn't aware of this when posting the question. Can I move it to DBA part of SO site?

Comment: Moderators have to do that, but usually only after sufficient votes.  I wouldn't worry about this question, but at least you know of a different resource now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just this last year I created a complicated, multi-part and multi-page report with graphs, summations, running averages, trends, "pivot-tables", etc. I did not count how many "rows" of data, but here are some things I did to manage the **many** queries:

- Most important lesson learned: After much optimization and attempts to consolidate and reuse queries and temporary tables, it still turns out that there is no set of "magic few" queries that will return the data you need. Even if you reduce the number of SQL queries from 45 to 35 (which would be impressive in many cases), there are still many queries that you need to manage in an intelligent way. The point is to worry more about writing manageable queries and good infrastructure, rather than making the focus on reducing the number. (If your process is similar, you'll inevitably have to add more queries and more details later anyway.)

  - Union queries indeed have their place and are sometimes necessary, but simply combining queries to "reduce the number" can have negative consequences. 1) Union queries cannot be built or visualized using the Design View. I consider myself a "real coder", but I still appreciate the ability to use UI components when I can. Design View offers various useful syntax and datatype checks. 2) It is often useful in debugging and optimization to be able to run queries individually. 3) Unions do not improve efficiency and might actually slow down queries when duplicate removal and sorting are not necessary. 4) I have experienced certain perfectly correct queries that result in errors when combined in Unions. I haven't learned how to predict this behavior so it's almost not worth mentioning... except to not be fooled into thinking that the individual queries are somehow flawed. (There are usually workarounds.)
- Create all related report queries and temporary tables in a separate Access database and link to the main database.  In other words, create a separate reporting front-end if possible.  Not only can this keep the source database cleaner, it can make it more efficient (highly dependent on number of users and how they're sharing the database).
- Name queries using a consistent pattern. I tried using numbered queries with some success. I personally find that descriptive names are more useful than short, cryptic names. Much cut and pasting becomes necessary however.
- VBA code or macros can be better than individual saved queries.

  - I rarely use complicated macros, so most of these tips are relevant to VBA code, but I won't argue against macros because they offer at least some similar benefits. It's also possible without much work to create a useful "dashboard" form that makes VBA code click-n-run similar to macros.
  - Comments can be included adjacent to the SQL.  This can be invaluable in outlining ugly SQL. For example, it can be worth explaining why you choose a LEFT JOIN with extra WHERE criteria instead of an INNER JOIN, especially to prevent "helpful" coworkers (or yourself) from rewriting a query just to find they failed to consider all the original contexts.
  - An entire sequence of query texts and execution can be traced and debugged live. If error handling is coded appropriately, you can create custom logs and specialized handling of errors. SQL text can be edited and rerun without stopping the entire process.
  - Query parameters can be passed to queries without awkward UI prompts.  Parameters can be used to code proper queries with user input (i.e. avoid SQL injection) and can reduce number of similar queries that simply have different input or criteria but are otherwise identical.
  - **Multiple queries can be wrapped in a transactions and all committed or rolled back together!**  Not sure whether macros support this.

Answer (score 1):

You can either move the SQL to VBA, to a macro, or if they're all appending to one table, make a large union subquery. All will reach that goal. For usability, I often go for the macro, since it's click to run. Just `SetWarnings` first, and then chain `RunSQL` statements.

The UNION query is also elegant solution if applicable.

Comment: Yes I use macro to run queries with SetWarnings to No, but again lot of queries.

Comment: And I don't see Union Query in Access 2000

Comment: You can put the SQL inside of the macro, don't use `OpenQuery` use `RunSQL` and copy-paste the SQL from your action queries. Obviously, you don't 'see' a union query in any pane, because you will need to write it by hand (there's no GUI for that).